# Compare multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2 dimensions array wich contains multiple arrays like so :

```
$schema = Array(
    Array("prestation_1" => 123, "prestataire_1" => 321, "prestation_2" => 456, "prestataire_2" => 654),
    Array("prestation_1" => 123, "prestataire_1" => 321, "prestation_2" => 456, "prestataire_2" => 654),
    Array("prestation_1" => 123, "prestataire_1" => 321, "prestation_2" => 456, "prestataire_2" => 654),
    Array("prestation_1" => 123, "prestataire_1" => 321, "prestation_2" => 456, "prestataire_2" => 654)
)
```

*Note : arrays in the main array always have the same structure (same keys)*

I want to know **if each array in my main array `$schema` are equivalent**.

If so, I want to return **one copy** of it, else I want to return an empty array.

I know I could compare array 2 by 2 in a foreach loop or something like that, but is there a proper way to achieve this?
I don't know, a sort of recursive function I could apply with an array_map() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
function checkArray($schema){
  $arr = array_unique($schema);
  if(count($arr) == 1){
     return $arr;
  }
  else{
     return array();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function check( $array)
{
    $array=array_values($array);
    $k=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
    {
      if(count($array)-1 > $i)
      {
          if($array[$i] == $array[$i+1])
             $k=0;
          else
             $k=1;
      }
    }
    if($k == 0)
     return $array[0];
    else
      return array(); 
}
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/JQpfo)

Answer (score 0):

```
function emptycheck($schema) {
    $schema=array_unique($schema);
    if(count($schema)=!1){
        $schema=array();//empty array
    }
    return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to compare them direcly - i.e.

```
$schema[0] == $schema[1]; // etc., checking for the same key/value pairs
```

or

```
$schema[0] === $schema[1]; // etc., checking whether key/value pairs, order and types are the same.
```

Otherwise you have to use some of the diff methods (there are with callback like array_udiff)
or to write your own method to compare them.